# Getting error saying "DecisionTreeClassif does not exist"

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn machion learning.  When I try to create a `DecisionTreeClassifier` it says cannot find reference `DecisionTreeClassifier`

```py
import sklearn as tree

// Get the error hear
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DecisionTreeClassifier belongs to the `tree` submodule of `sklearn`, so you have to import it. This should work:

```
import sklearn.tree as tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```